# FPGA MOTOR CONTROL

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, redundancy, nios

I'm going to implement a motor control based on FPGA with a NIOS II soft processor, I need the system to meet the requirements of TUV and IEC 61508 certificates. 
I have read one solution to use a redundancy system, but I couldn't understand how I can do that?
and, does the redundancy system need a physical hardware to be added as an addition with the FPGA? or is there anther soft solution like adding a soft processor such as NIOS II?

Comment: Your solution depends a lot on your target SIL level.

Answer (score 0):

61508 defines a process, follow the process.

1. Why are you using an FPGA?
2. Why not just use a processor?
3. What does the soft processor bring you other than a language that you are
   happy with - which brings be back to question 1 and 2
4. Your design decisions depend very heavily on what SIL level you are aiming for.

You might be better giving a specific question, your question is very general and vague.

Comment: hello trig
I need to know what steps should I follow to do a safety motor control.

FPGA is suitable fo my application, FPGA give my flexibility, and scalability, and help me in the development in the future.

Comment: the steps you should follow to do a safety motor control are detailed in the IEC61508 document. The IEC61508 document can be purchased [here](https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/22273)